# How to make props immutable to prevent rerender in React?

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs

I have been creating a small app using react.js. I take 'performance' into account excessively.

So I have a simple child component named "Spinner". My goal is to make sure this component never re-renders.

Here is my component:

```
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';

export default class Spinner extends PureComponent {

render() {
    return (
        <div className="spinner">
            <div className="bounce1"></div>
            <div className="bounce2"></div>
            <div className="bounce3"></div>
        </div>
    )
}

}
```

In the time of the re-rendering with 'react-addons-perf', the component is always rendering, I am using PureComponent because I want that component to render only one time, I read that I can use immutable props but I don't know how to make this possible.

If I make some like to this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.renderState = false;
}

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return (this.renderState === undefined) ? true : this.renderState;
}
```

It is rendering only one time, but I believe that there is a better way.

How do I avoid the re-render? or maybe How I can make a immutable props?

Answer (score 7):

You don't need an extra logic for componentShouldUpdate, since you don't want your component to rerender ever.

Adding only this should be enough to prevent component to rerender:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For stateless components that don't need props, we can use a combination of a [Functional](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components) (stateless) component, and babel's [`React constant elements transformer`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-react-constant-elements/) to optimize the component creation, and prevent rerenders entirely.

1. Add `React constant elements transformer` to your build system. According to the [docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-react-constant-elements/) the transformer will:

   > Hoists element creation to the top level for subtrees that are fully
   >   static, which reduces call to React.createElement and the resulting
   >   allocations. More importantly, it tells React that the subtree hasn’t
   >   changed so React can completely skip it when reconciling.
2. Change the spinner to a stateless component.

   ```
   const Spinner = () => (
     <div className="spinner">
       <div className="bounce1"></div>
       <div className="bounce2"></div>
       <div className="bounce3"></div>
     </div>
   );

   export default Spinner;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your props immutable in React by using [Immutable JS](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) to transform your array props into [Lists](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List) and object props int [Maps](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map). With this library you can use simple checks to check the equality of arrays/objects (instead of going through keys/values for equality):

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) => {
   this.props.complexObjectAsMap === nextProps.complexObjectAsMap
}
```

But since your component doesn't have any props - this doesn't look the right question. In your case I'd go with [Ori Drori](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5157454/ori-drori) answer.